# ITMS-90725: SDK version issue with the iOS 16.4 SDK

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store-connect, testflight, bitrise

I have faced this warning:

When I submited the app to TestFlight using `Bitrise`, I got this warning from App Store Connect:

```
ITMS-90725: SDK version issue - This app was built with the iOS 16.4 SDK. Starting April 29, 2024, all iOS and iPadOS apps must be built with the iOS 17 SDK or later, included in Xcode 15 or later, in order to be uploaded to App Store Connect or submitted for distribution.
```

I have found the following solution [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/747459), but I do not know how or from where I can set `runner`!

```
Had to update the runner to macos-13
macos-latest defaults to version 12 which does not support xcode 15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solution:

On Bitrise, go to the `Stack & Machines` and then select Xcode 15 :)

[image]

Comment: Oh, you got it.

Comment: @son Yes, I got it but also thank you for the response :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to open your app at [bitrise.io](https://bitrise.io). Then go to the `Workflow` tab (Workflow Editor), and on the `Stack` tab select the compatible Xcode version.

They also list all Xcode versions [here](https://stacks.bitrise.io/stack_reports/osx-xcode-15.3.x-edge/).